# How append an object to a bytes array?

Tags: solidity

I have a function which staticcalls a function which returns 3 different variables `(uint112 reserve0, uint112 reserve1, uint32 blockTimestampLast)`.

```
(bool success, bytes memory result) = contractAddr.staticcall(signatureID);
```

After the call, I would like to add the `contractAddr` variable (which has an address type) to the `result` byte array.

Based on the questions I found, I tried to use the following lines to add the address:

```
result[3] = abi.encodePacked(contractAddr);
```

And then got this error:

```
TypeError: Type bytes memory is not implicitly convertible to expected type bytes1.
```

I know this is because `result` is `memory` and it can't be altered. To fix this I tried to create a new `bytes[]` but got the `TypeError: Type bytes1 is not implicitly convertible to expected type bytes memory.` error when I tried the following:

```
  (bool success, bytes memory result) = contractAddr.staticcall(signatureID);
  bytes[] memory resultsCurrent = new bytes[](4);
  resultsCurrent[0] = result[0];
  resultsCurrent[1] = result[1];
  resultsCurrent[2] = result[2];
  resultsCurrent[3] = abi.encodePacked(contractAddr);
```

My question is, how could I create a `bytes` type variable which holds the three object of `result` at the index of `0,1,2` and `abi.encodePacked(contractAddr)` at the index of `3`? My goal is to compose a view function from it to avoid paying gas fee for the calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is, the returned result from staticcall is **not of a type bytes array, but bytes**. So your function will not work as intended anyhow. Depending on what you want to achieve you have a few options.

1. Encode address with result, where rez is of type bytes: `rez = abi.encodePacked(result, contractAddr);`
2. Create bytes array and pass result as first element and address as second

```
bytes[] memory resultsCurrent= new bytes[](2); 
resultsCurrent[0] = result; 
resultsCurrent[1] = abi.encodePacked(contractAddr);
```